# Does TortoiseSVN leave any logs of the merge?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

When I merge with TSVN, is there a text file where I can see in which files there were conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did the merge you already solved the conflicts. Furthermore TortoiseSVN nor SVN do record the files which where in conflict. So the answer is no. There is no file generated. If you didn't solved the conflicts you can see the files which are in conflict via TortoiseSVN "Check for Modification" or on command line via

```
svn status
```

The lines which are prefixed by a "C"

Answer (score 0):

If you have conflicts after **Update** operation, then you see red lines in log window:

```
Conflicted: path/file
```

Then, you if you go to **path** will see **file.[rev1]** and **file.[rev2]**: the latest version of the file from repo, the version of the file after the last successful update, and of course you have your working version of the file - **file.mine**. So, you can resolve conflicts manually or activate a TSVN menu with options (right click on line):

```
Edit conflicts               -> goes to two-side editor
Resolve conflicts using "theirs" -> drop own changes -> Attention! (changes will be lost)
Resolve conflicts using "mine"   -> drop others changes  (others' changes can be restored)
...
```

In any case, this menu can be activated from the main TSVN menu -> **Resolved...**.